# Trying to populate Django app database with Faker

Tags: python, django, faker

I am trying to populate Django database with Faker.
I created a Django project (name = first_project) and then I created a Django app (name = first_app).
I created models in my app and then I created a file named 'populate_first_app.py' in my main first_project folder(the one which contains manage.py) and filled in with the following code:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')
 
import django
django.setup()
 
import random
from first_app.models import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord
from faker import Faker
 
fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search','Social','Marketplace','News','Games']
 
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
 
def populate(N=5):
 
    for entry in range(N):
 
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()
 
        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]
 
        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("populating script!")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")
```

after making migrations and running the code, my terminal shows:

```
(MyDjangoEnv) E:\Django\first_project>python populate_first_app.py
populating script!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 34, in <module>
    populate(20)
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 28, in populate
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 573, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1258, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Users\vedan\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1481, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'topic' into field. Choices are: Topic, Topic_id, accessrecord, id, name, url
```

Can someone please help me?
PS: I am a newbie and this is my first question here.

THANKYOU :)

Comment: You don't share your model, but from the error message I'm fairly confident in thinking you should change the `topic=top` in the `get_or_create` call to `Topic=top`

Comment: yes, I changed it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Topic` instead of `topic` in `get_or_create()` method.

```py
webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(Topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]
```

Comment: It works ,thanks.  I checked the video of my instructor and he had 'topic' but it still ran fine

Comment: You need to have the exact same name in the model. Maybe he's using `topic` in his model?

Comment: No, the models were Topic, Webpage, and AccessRecord

Comment: I am sorry!  you were right .I accidentally confused it with the model name (which were Topic, Webpage, and AccessRecord). thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you think this is the solution to your problem, please mark it with the green checkmark so that people with the same problem can find the answer quickly.